# Does this method return int Nrows and int Ncols?

Tags: c

I am completely new to C programming (only do java) and the statements are different enough to confuse me.
I was wondering if my method header states that I need to declare Nrows and Ncols (from my main method) within the method? is simply setting them to a certain variable enough?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void RdSize(int *Nrows, int *Ncols)
{
    Nrows = NULL;
    Ncols = NULL;
    FILE *in = fopen("A1in.txt","r");
    if(in == NULL) { perror("Error opening file");}
    else
    {   
        int i;
        char input[4];  //I have no idea how to set the size of the array to
                        //the length of the first line of the input file 
                        //(which has 4 chars, but is not optimal to put the 
                        //number 4)

        for(i = 0; i < sizeof(input); i++)
        {
            input[i] = fgetc(in);   //trying to copy each char into input[] 
                                    //array

            if(isdigit(input[i]) && Nrows == NULL)
            {
                Nrows = input[i] - '0'; //converting from char to int
            }                           //Here I'm setting Nrows to
                                        //something. Is this all I do?
            if(isdigit(input[i]) && Nrows != NULL)
            {
                Ncols = input[i] - '0'; //converting from char to int
            }                           //setting Ncols
        }
    }
    fclose(in);
}
```

Also if I had a .txt document that looked like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

What would be the best way to put this into a 2d char array from the .txt file?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You say the first line of the file has 4 characters, but the example you show has 13 characters. Which is it?

Comment: You shouldn't assign to `Nrows` and `Ncols`. Since they're pointers, you need to indirect through them to set the caller's variable: `*Nrows = <something>;`

Comment: It's very unclear what this function is supposed to do. You need to explain it clearly, and what's going wrong.

Comment: The .txt document that I showed there has nothing to do with what I wish to accomplish. It is sort of another thing that I was wondering about.

Comment: Post one question at a time, and explain it clearly.

Comment: The line that I want to put into the char array is "9_6_" where _ is a space.

Comment: You need to add an extra character for the null terminator of the string. So if it contains 4 characters, it must be declared `char input[5];`. Any C tutorial should explain this.

Comment: The task is to: "Read from an input file two integers for the number of rows and number of columns of the image to be processed." Then it gives me the exact header that is in my method and tells me to do the rest of the method. Why does it give me pointers int *Nrows and int *Ncols if I have to fetch the file myself, read the two integers in the first line and then display them? Since this is a void method, I can't return any variable and since there are pointers in the header, I cannot assign them to the integers within the top line.   What is the point of the pointers in the header?

Comment: Two integers can be more than 4 characters. If the two numbers are `100 50` that's 5 characters plus 2 spaces after each.

Comment: You should probably use `fscanf()`, that way you don't have to worry about how long they are.

Comment: The pointers are used to point to the caller's variables. You're going to fill in the variables that they point to with the numbers you read.

Comment: You definitely need to read a good textbook on how pointers are used in C.

Comment: So if I use fscanf(), the contents would be fscanf(in, "%s", input)? Since you said that the two integers can be more than 4 characters, and there can be more spaces, how could I separate the two integers and put them into the array? Also, will this fscanf() only scan the first line of the .txt file? I'm afraid that it will go into all of the lines because I have many more integers sitting there. What would I replace the input array with in that statement? fscanf(in, "%s", _____)?

Comment: No, it would be `fscanf(in, "%d %d", Nrows, Ncols);`

Comment: The whole point is to use `fscanf()` to parse the file into numbers, and not go through a string at all.

Comment: And I would replace the for loop with this? Where in the code would you recommend to place this? I hope I'm not bothering you too much.

Comment: Also would this statement assign the values that are within the .txt file to the locations that Nrows and Ncols point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read two numbers from the first line of the file, you can simply use `fscanf()` in place of the loop.

```
void RdSize(int *Nrows, int *Ncols)
{
    FILE *in = fopen("A1in.txt","r");
    if(in == NULL) { 
        perror("Error opening file");
        return;
    }
    if (fscanf(in, "%d %d", Nrows, Ncols) != 2) {
        printf("Error reading size\n");
    }
    fclose(in);
}
```

`%d` means to parse an integer in the file. The numbers are written to the memory that `Nrows` and `Ncols` point to, which are the caller's variables.

Comment: So if I were to use this method in my main method, and then use the variables that I threw into this method, they would have changed to what I did within this method? Say in my main method I do int x = 2; int y = 3;, then do RdSize(x, y); then do printf("%d %d", x ,y), they would be different?

Comment: It should be `RdSize(&x, &y);` in the calling function. You *really* need to learn the language. SO is not a programming class.

Comment: You delete `Nrows = NULL;  Ncols = NULL;` and `fclose(in);` move into else-block.

Comment: Okay thank you very much Barmar for your help, I am starting to learn C, but I surely cannot learn it within a day. I've upvoted your answer, but newcomers cannot give official upvotes. I surely hope you get the top answer for this! I also appreciate your help BLUEPIXY!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks, copied too much from the original. I simplified it by just putting a `return;` in the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

The sort answer is no. Just like Java the parameters of a method / function should be defined elsewhere and passed in...the purpose of parameters.

`Nrows` and `Ncols` are `int` pointers, meaning that instead of hold a value itself, they store the address in memory that the value is held, which can be access by dereferencing the pointer by prefixing it with `*`, such as `*Ncols`.

I suggest reading and learning more about pointers as they play huge roles in programming in C/C++.

https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node10.html